# If in a group $G$, we have $a^5 = e$ and $aba^{-1} = b^2$ for some $a$, $b$ in $G$, then what is the order of $b$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If in a group $G$, we have $a^5 = e$ and $aba^{-1} = b^2$ for some $a$, $b$ in $G$, then what is the order of $b$? Here $e$ denotes the identity element in $G$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not hard to see that $a^nba^{-n}=b^{2^n}$. Thus, $b^{31}=1$. Note that $31$ is prime and so $o(b)=31$ or $b=1$.

Comment: Babak Miraftab, there are bound to be other solutions, but what is important is the fact that this solution is so simple and uses only the elementary facts about groups.

Comment: Can we find a concrete example of a group having two elements satisfying these conditions?

Comment: Sorry, I can't see where $a^n b a^{-n} = b^{2^n}$ comes from. I tried taking both sides of the equation to the $n$, but then I am stuck at $(aba^{-1})^n$. Also, why does this equation imply that $b^{31} = 1$?

Comment: @user127001 Note that $a^2ba^{-2}=a^1b^2a^{-1}=(a^1ba^{-1})^2$.

Comment: @user127001 Put $n=5$ in the equation.

Comment: @BabakMiraftab: chera man ino nadide budam. Good to go for 10 :)

Comment: @BabakS.lotf dari Babak jan. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Lino : Since $31$ is prime, $o(b)=31$. Indeed, suppose that $n=o(b)$ with $0<n<31$.Then write $31=qn+r$ with $0\leq r<n$. Since $e=b^{31}=b^{qn+r}=b^r$ and $n=o(b)$, we must have $r=0$. Therefore, $31=qn$, with $n<31$. Since $31$ is prime, we must have $q=31$ and $n=1$. But then $b^1=b=e$, which we are implicitly not to be the case...

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more general result.

If $G$ is a group and $a$,$b$ $\in$ $G$ with $bab^{-1} = a^r$ for some $r$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$, then $b^jab^{-j} = a^{r^j}$ for all $j$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$

Proof : We use induction. The base case is trivial. Let the hypothesis be true for some natural number $k$. We have :

$b^{j+1}ab^{-(j+1)} = b(b^jab^{-j})b^{-1} = ba^{r^j}b^{-1} = (bab^{-1})^{r^j} = (a^r)^{r^j} = a^{r.r^j} = a^{r^{j+1}}$

QED.

Now you can proceed as Babak did. This is taken from an exercise in Hungerford's Algebra.